# Comparison of "measures"

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to re-propose an issue that opened in another topic.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ an algebra of sets and let $\mu_{0}$ a finite and $\sigma$- additive measure.

We denote with $\mathcal{F_\sigma}$ the family all countable unions of sets of $\mathcal{F}$ and with $\mathcal{F_\delta}$ the family all  countable intersection of sets of $\mathcal{F}$.

We extend $\mu_{0}$ to two family $\mathcal{F_\sigma}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\delta}$ in the following way:

if $A\in\mathcal{F_{\sigma}}$ 
\begin{equation}
\mu_{1}(A)=\sup\{\mu_{0}(A'), A'\subset A,\; A'\in\mathcal{F}\}
\end{equation}
else if $B\in\mathcal{F_\delta}$
\begin{equation}
\mu_{2}(B)=\inf\{\mu_{0}(B'), B'\supset B,\; B'\in\mathcal{F}\}.
\end{equation}

We know that a measure is monotone, but in this case $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ 
they are different, furthermore they are not really measures.

If $B\subset A$, I think that $\mu_2(B)<\mu_1(A)$, but my doubt resides here:

Let $B\subset A$, where $B\in\mathcal{F_\delta}$ and $A\in\mathcal{F_\sigma}$

if $A'$, $B'\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $B'\subset A'$ for all $A'\subset A$ and $B'\supset B$, then $\mu_0(B')<\mu_0(A')$, therefore
\begin{equation}
inf_{B'\supset B} \{\mu_0 (B')\}<sup_{A'\subset A} \{\mu_0 (A')\},
\end{equation}
then,

\begin{equation}
\mu_2(B)<\mu_1(A).
\end{equation}

Now, from the definition of $\mu_2$, $B'$ must contain $B$, 
therefore $B'$ it could contain $A$, therefore $A'$, in this case exists a set of $\mathcal{F}$ for which $\mu_0(B')>\mu_0(A')$.

Same thing if $A'\subset B$.

So how do we prove that, if $B\subset A$, then $\mu_2(B)<\mu_1(A)$, 
without assuming that $B'\subset A'$ for all $B'\supset B$ and $A'\subset A$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the symbol $\subset$ allows set equality.  (See **note** below.)  So I will write $\subseteq$ to avoid confusing myself.

We are given: $\mu_0$ is finite and sigma-additive.  So: if $A_n \in \mathcal F$, $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ and $\bigcap A_n = A \in \mathcal F$, then $\lim \mu_0(A_n) = \mu_0(A)$.  And similarly for an increasing sequence.

**Claim.** Let $B \in \cal F_\delta$, $A \in \cal F_\sigma$, $B \subseteq A$.  Then: $\mu_2(B) \le \mu_1(A)$.
Note: we cannot prove strict inequality $\mu_2(B) < \mu_1(A)$, contrary to the claim in the OP.

By definition of $\mu_1$, there is a sequence $A_n \in \cal F$, $A_n \subseteq A$ with $\lim \mu_0(A_n) = \mu_1(A)$.  Since $A \in \cal F_\sigma$, we may assume $\bigcup A_n = A$.   By taking finite unions, we may assume $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$.

By definition of $\mu_2$, there is a sequence $B_n \in \cal F$, $B_n \supseteq B$ with $\lim \mu_0(B_n) = \mu_2(B)$.  Since $B \in \cal F_\delta$, we may assume $\bigcap B_n = B$.   By taking finite intersections, we may assume $B_1 \supseteq B_2 \supseteq \cdots$.

Then we have $B_n \setminus A_n \in \cal F$, $B_1 \setminus A_1 \supseteq B_2 \setminus A_2 \supseteq \cdots$, and $\bigcap (B_n\setminus A_n) = B \setminus A = \varnothing \in \cal F$.  So $\lim \mu_0(B_n \setminus A_n) = 0$.

Compute
$$
\mu_0(B_n) = \mu_0(B_n \cap A_n)+\mu_0(B_n \setminus A_n)
\le \mu_0(A_n)+\mu_0(B_n\setminus A_n) .
$$
Then let $n \to \infty$ to get
$$
\mu_2(B) \le \mu_1(A)+0 = \mu_1(A),
$$
as required.

**note**
This does not work if the symbol $\subset$ is strict inclusion in the definitions $\mu_1, \mu_2$.
*Example.* In set $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ let $\mathcal F$ be the power set, let $\mu_0$ be counting measure.  Take $B=\{1,2\}$, $A=\{1,2,3\}$.  Then:

Any $A' \subset A$ has at most two elements, so $\mu_1(A) = 2$.
Any $B' \supset B$ has at least $3$ elements, so $\mu_2(B) = 3$.
So we have $B \subset A$ but not $\mu_2(B) \le \mu_1(A)$.